# How to resume from the last screen of the app after the user has pressed home once?

Tags: java, android, android-homebutton

In my app I have a requirement that if the Home button is pressed during the working of app and if the user starts the app from the icon from home screen it must resume from the last activity.

How do I save the last screen history and resume it from the same screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out following posts:

- [Android - restore last viewed Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450019/android-restore-last-viewed-activity),
- [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state).

Comment: I am glad you found solution. :)

Answer (score 6):

The [`AlwaysRetainTaskState`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always) might be what you're looking for.

In your `AndroidManifest`, in the activity tag, just add

```
android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
```

Comment: Dude this is working fine on emulator but not on device!! Is there any issue??

Comment: It should work too. If the device somehow lacks memory, the application will be killed anyway and you will lose the stack, but this usually doesn't happen...
If you want the app to keep the state even after device reboot, then you'll need to save the state, for example in a SharedPreference, and restore it when needed.

Comment: If the system needs to kill your activity to free memory, it will call onSaveInstanceState, so you can implement your own task saving/restoring mechanism in that case.